# Unity. Как сделать зону взаимодействия игрока с объетами (2d платформер)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в Юнити, прошу не кидаться тапками.
Игра на Unity, простенький 2d платформер. Хочу сделать переход на другую локацию в таком простеньком виде (скрипт собираюсь использовать и для других объектов по такой же механике): Игрок заходит в определённую зону (сзади находится нужный спрайт) и если в этой зоне он нажмёт E, совершается переход на следующий уровень/другое действие. Я слышал про триггеры, но абсолютно не могу придумать как реализовать такую конструкцию. Подскажите пожалуйста, если не сложно, то поподробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно прикрепить коллайдеры на вашего игрока и саму дверь(или что у вас там). На коллайдере двери поменять значение `IsTrigger` в `true` и написать скрипт, в котором будет находиться метод `OnTriggerEnter2D`, [вот ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html),
в котором вы проверяете нажатие кнопки с помощью `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))`, [вот ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html), вы загружаете сцену с помощью `Application.LoadLevel()`, [вот ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html). Скрипт советую кинуть на саму дверь.

Comment: Этот метод будет работать, но игрок может стоять, например, спиной к двери, а нужно чтобы дверь открывалась только когда игрок на неё смотритю

Comment: добавь коллайдер перед игроком и его проверяй уже